# In Nix, why does hashDrv replace the inputDrvs with a recursive hashDrv of their contents

Tags: nix

In Section 5.4 of Eelco Dolstra's thesis on page 108 there is a definition of the `hashDrv` function in which, on box 69, the `inputDrvs` are replaced (recursively) with the `hashDrv` of the parsed contents of the file.  I don't understand the motivation for performing this substitution as opposed to just using the the `inputDrvs` file names themselves without perform a substitution.

The consequence of this substitution appears to be that the output values of store derivations are recursively removed from the computation of all output values.  However, since the output values themselves are computed from all the other data that goes into `hashDrv`, there doesn't seem to be any positive consequences for doing this substitution operation.

Indeed there appears to be negative consequences because this substitution means that the output hash file cannot be computed from the derivation contents itself, and instead you are required to have the entire tree of input derivations to perform the computation (see https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2789#issuecomment-595143352).

While of course the output hash value for the derivation itself needs to be excluded from the computation of its `hashDrv`, it seems like it would have been better if the output hash values were simply derived from just the other contents of the derivation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so first all, it would be better still to just drop the `inputDrvs` and just use the output paths of those inputs for creating the store path, see the commit message of https://github.com/nixos/nix/commit/1511aa9f488ba0762c2da0bf8ab61b5fde47305d for Eelco saying as much:

> Note that this is a privileged operation, because you can construct a
> derivation that builds any store path whatsoever. Fixing this will
> require changing the hashing scheme (i.e., the output paths should be
> computed from the other fields in BasicDerivation, allowing them to be
> verified without access to other derivations). However, this would be
> quite nice because it would allow .drv-free building (e.g. "nix-env
> -i" wouldn't have to write any .drv files to disk).

But, the `hashDrv` given is better than one that just hashes the drv as-is, because the "modulo fixed output derivations part". By ignoring the rest fixed output derivations and just returning a hash based on the fixed output hash (and name) alone, we gain the ability to change how fixed output derivations produce the data they do without changing downstream hashes. This how in Nixpkgs today, we can for example do https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/82130 and it won't be a mass rebuild.

Comment: I get that for fixed output derivations, it makes sense to ignore the build instructions, but my question is about the line marked with box 69, which only applies to non-fixed output derivations.

Comment: The point of the "modulo" part is not the fixed output derivations themselves, but the regular derivations that depend on them.

At a minimum, say the `inputDrv` was only replaced with something if the immediate dependency was a fixed output derivation.

Now what do we do for another regular derivation downstream of the first one? It should reflect that the middle one was normalized somehow, and not just refer to the original unnormalized derv path.

Comment: I get it now.  The path of a fixed derivation file is a hash of the contents of the file, including the build instructions.  So when we include a direct (or even indirect) dependency on a fixed derivation we want to exclude those build instructions from our digest.